# Tool using selenium for mobile testing

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, robotium, seetest

I am developing a tool with keyword driven testing for Mobile Applications.
Is there any way to use the Selenium for Mobile testing without using Appium or any other tool in between ?

Also, apart from multiple platform support what is the difference in using selenium and robotium for Android application testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to use the Selenium for Mobile testing without using Appium or any other tool in between ?

Appium is just a tool for automating mobile apps, and Appium is just a wrapper for Selenium.

The answer is "Yes", there is a way you can use just Selenium.  One thing you can do, is at the beginning of all your tests, you could resize the browser to phone sizes, so responsive sites will change to the mobile version.

> what is the difference in using selenium and robotium for Android application testing

Selenium tests web browsers.  That's it.  Robotium is a full-fledged framework for automating *Native* apps.  Selenium can't interact with apps unless they are **web apps**.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of Application for mobile:
1. Native app -> Was written in native language (Java, C,...), full compatibility with target platform. -> In this case we can use Native testing framework such as Robotium for Android.
2. Web app -> Was written in HTML, javascript... -> In this type, we can use selenium to test the web app.
3. Hybird app -> Was written in HTML, javascript but was ported to targer platform (such as Android, iOS, BB...), in this case, we can use both of them (selenium and robotium). Robotium test in ADT (Android development tool), we can use ClickOnWebElement... or anything similar to interact with web browser (web view in Activity). We also can use selenium to test web application before port them into target platform in web browser.

Answer (score 1):

By the time I am posting this reply you may have already developed your tool with keyword driven testing for Mobile Applications. If so, I would love to learn about it from you, if you still haven't done it yet, the below answers maybe useful to you.

Since you mentioned trying to automate Android Applications, a good alternative for appium could be [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/) and [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Getting-Started) which are the other open source tools that are widely used and have a lot of support online. One reason people go with Appium is you can have the same code base that would work for both iOS and Android. You wont get this flexibility with Espresso or Robotium.

This is something to think about if in the future your company decides to do iOS app implementation as well.

For you other question. Robotium is pretty much like Selenium for Android app testing. It has very similar features. Read this article for more info - https://www.360logica.com/blog/robotium-selenium-android/

Hopefully this gives you some idea about the differences and similarities.

Answer (score 0):

"If you are seeking for a full solution, you should take a look at [SeeTest Automation](https://experitest.com/test-automation-tool-for-mobile-testing-continuous-integration/). It will give you the ability to develop automated 
tests that will work on all devices, without changing anything in your test (even cross-platform). "

Comment: Could you use it with existing tests with specflow and selenium?